# Animations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my Javascript project.
In this project I have to create some animations.
In this specific case, I have to make a ball bounce up and down.
The code below works great just from the top to the bottom, but not viceversa.

```
var div = document.getElementById('container-ball');

function createBall(event)
{
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY; 
    var newBall = document.createElement('div');
    newBall.style.position = "absolute"
    newBall.style.width = '15px';
    newBall.style.height = '15px';
    var bx = newBall.style.left = x + 'px';
    var by = newBall.style.top = y + 'px';
    newBall.style.borderRadius = '10px';
    newBall.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    var incrementPos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(bounce, 5);


    function bounce() 
    {
        incrementPos++;
        by = newBall.style.top = incrementPos + y + "px";
    
        if(by == 650 + "px")
        {
            clearInterval(id)
            var id2 = setInterval(function bounceUp()
            {
                incrementPosYMax -= 650
                by = newBall.style.bottom = by + "px" - incrementPosYMax
            }, 5)
        }`/*Function that make the ball bounce down and up(but when it came at 650 px it stopped )*/ì
    } /*End of the set interval */`
    div.appendChild(newBall);
}
div.addEventListener("click", createBall);
```

This down below is the HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id ="container-ball">
        
    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're very close to having a [mcve] here.  Could you attach some CSS and put this all in a working snippet in the question?  And then be more specific in how the output fails to meet your requirements?  As it currently stands this does not run, so readers coming to the question won't understand how it currently performs and how you need it to behave differently.

Comment: The css is not a lot is only a width and height of my div:#container-ball{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

Comment: and in my javascript code i made a ball with the click of my mouse, when i click it start from a position by and it goes down when reach the ma-height of the screen it dowsnt go up, is this my problem

Comment: This is well suited for something like a canvas.  A ball bouncing can be approximated using the absolute value of a trig function.  E.g. `Math.abs(Math.cos(x))`, where `x` is based on time.  Animations should happen in an animation frame (`window.requestAnimationFrame`).

Comment: yeah i saw some wxample with the canvas but my teacher want to use the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example (comments see below):

```js
const areaHeight = 150; // it is 650px in the original question

var div = document.getElementById('container-ball');

function createBall(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var newBall = document.createElement('div');
  newBall.className = 'ball';
  var bx = newBall.style.left = x + 'px';
  var by = newBall.style.top = y + 'px';
  var incrementPos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(bounce, 5);

  let direction = 1; // 1 = down, -1 = up

  function bounce() {
    incrementPos += direction;
    by = newBall.style.top = incrementPos + y + "px";

    if (by == areaHeight + "px" || by == y + 'px') {
      direction = -direction;
    }
  }
  
  div.appendChild(newBall);
}
```

```css
#container-ball {
  width: 300px;
  height: 157px;
  background: gray;
}

#container-ball .ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-ball" onclick="createBall(event)"></div>
Click on the grey box
```

Now, the explanation.

1. I've moved ball's styles to CSS - this is easier to control in the future. So when I have a class for ball, I can write in my code: `newBall.className = 'ball';`
2. I removed `incrementPosYMax` because I do not really understand if you need it
3. I understand your 'bounce' as bounce, so my ball just fall to the floor and then return to the original position. I do not really understand if you mean that (please, comment if it is wrong).
4. Your program is quite small, so I do not see the need for another `setInterval`, so all the animation in my example is inside only one `setInterval`
5. I've added new variable `direction` to control the direction for the ball (1 = down, -1 = up)
6. I do not like the parts with `by == areaHeight + "px"`, but I keep them for you, because you use it in your code.
7. This code have some bugs, that you (or me if you ask) can fix. I just need to understand that my approach is correct

How the direction works:

1. Take a look at this line `by = newBall.style.top = incrementPos + y + "px";` here you set new "y" coordinate for the ball as sum of 'original' "y" coordinate (in `y`) and offset (the distance that ball moved over the time) in `incrementPos`. So, if you increase `incrementPos`, then the ball's position will be lower (because "zero" in browser is at the top left corner, bigger "y" means lower the element).
2. Before my change, in your code you changed the offset with this line: `incrementPos++;` (means you increase `incrementPos` by 1 on every bounce step).
3. To move to another direction, you need to subtract 1 on every bounce step.
4. To reflect the "direction" of that move, I've added `direction` variable (so 1 means move down, and -1 means move up)
5. Now the offset is changed by: `incrementPos += direction;` (so I add this `direction`, not always 1)
6. Sometimes we need to change the "direction" with this code: `direction = -direction;`
7. The "levels" where we need to change direction is checked by this code: `if (by == areaHeight + "px" || by == y + 'px')` - here we check bottom (`areaHeight`) and top (`y` - it is where user clicks the mouse)

Comment: Ty i work fine now i adapted with my code but i dont undestand the direction if you can explain it to me because where are u decrementinf the pixel when it bouncing down ?

Comment: @SHlMRJ I've added this to the answer also

Comment: There was an error in my code (`div.appendChild(newBall);` was inside of `bounce` function), but I fixed it (my answer is now edited)